# How to add one extra field to contact database?

Tags: android

I want to add one field(column) to contact fields,that i can set value for that field in code and mobile user can not see that field in contact properties.In this way i can use contact information without create another database to copy contact database.
Is this possible?
please help me

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can modify the contacts database directly (or at least not without rooting the device first).

If you want to add additional information to a stored contact, I think your best option would be to actually create a new database. Just create a new table with columns `[CONTACT_ID, YOUR_NEW_FIELD]` and store that extra piece of information on the contact there. Also, that way you won't be polluting the contact's database with your app's proprietary information, which would have no meaning if the user removed your app.